# How to change the default registration in django

Tags: html, css, django

[image]I have used django's default registration. I want to edit this forms because it's appearance does not look very good to me. I want to convert the instructions into tool tip or something better looking how can I do it?I am new to django
[image: registration page looks like this]([![enter image description here])

html

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header" style="background-image: url('/static/img/tele-bg.jpg');">

            <div class="title-container text-center">
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                   <form method="post">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                       {{ form.as_p }}
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                   </form>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use django bootstrap forms or you can make your own custom tempalate for registering the user.
If you want django bootstrap form which are pretty good you can try like this:

First install `pip install django-bootstrap4`

Then add the `bootstrap4` into your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...........
    'bootstrap4',]
```

Then you can render the forms in your template with this tag:

```
 {% load bootstrap4 %}
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header" style="background-image: url('/static/img/tele-bg.jpg');">

            <div class="title-container text-center">
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                   <form method="post">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                    {% bootstrap_form form %}
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                   </form>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** This is just a demo you can change this design as you want:

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header" style="background-image: url('/static/img/tele-bg.jpg');">

                <div class="title-container text-center">
                        <h2>Register</h2>
                       <form method="post">
                       {% csrf_token %}
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password"><br>
 Password Confirmation:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                       </form>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: now the text bars appear very large. I am uploading a picture in the question please see

Comment: @HassanIkram then you can design your own template for this as you want

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: just remove `{{form.as_p}}` and write your own design code for this

Comment: @HassanIkram i edited my answer you can check it and customize it as you want